# Advanced polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I have classes in advanced programming at my university and I have a little trouble understanding how this code works.

```
public final class GenericClass<T> {
    private void overloadedMethod(Collection<?> o) {
        System.out.println("Collection<?>");
    }

    private void overloadedMethod(List<Number> o) {
        System.out.println("List<Number>");
    }

    private void overloadedMethod(ArrayList<Integer> o) {
        System.out.println("ArrayList<Integer>");
    }

    public void method(List<T> l) {
        overloadedMethod(l);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericClass<Integer> test = new GenericClass<Integer>();
        test.method(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}
```

Why does this code print "Collection<?>"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The declaration of `method(List<T> l)` does not specify any bounds on the type T. There is no guarantee that T is Number or a subclass of Number. Therefore, the compiler can only decide that this method calls `overloadedMethod(Collection<?> o)`.

Remember: after compilation, the information about generics is not available anymore in the class files.

Comment: thanks, your answer explains even why after changing `overloadedMethod(List<Number> o)` to `overloadedMethod(List<?> o)` program prints out `List<Number>` instead of `Collection<?>`

Comment: the most important thing is your last sentence. That explains everything!

Comment: Pretty good answer, but -1 to draw your attention to the fact that declaring `GenericClass<T extends Number>` instead results in the same call to `overloadedMethod(Collection<?>)`. So there's something else going on here.

Comment: Hint: it would only work if you changed to `overloadedMethod(List<? extends Number> o)`.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you define a generic type, a corresponding raw type is automatically provided
This method

```
public void method(List<T> l) {

}
```

is replacing with

```
public void method(List<Object> l) {

}
```

If You read about Wildcard types, You will see that `List<Number>` and `List<Object>`
or `ArrayList<Integer>` and `List<Object>` hasn't any type relationship. `List<Object>` is a subtype of the `Collecion<?>` therefore this method is called.

Comment: Actually, the reasoning here isn't enough to answer the question. The compiler decides which method overload to call, which happens *before* type erasure.

Answer (score -1):

when you deal with method overloading you must put three concepts in your mind:

1. Widening
2. Boxing
3. Var_args

your problem lies in the first point which is widening, the java compiler gives priorities to each of these concepts the same order as they are listed above, so it prefers widening and when you call your method as `test.method(new ArrayList<Integer>());`
 the compiler finds that `ArrayList<Integer>()` could be widened to `Collection<?>` and since it has the highest priority it calls these version and neglects the other ones
Note: if you change the declaration of the other two methods to `private void overloadedMethod(ArrayList<?> o)` and `private void overloadedMethod(List<?> o)` the compiler will also call the `Collection<?>` version because it's the preferred one

Comment: No. if private void overloadedMethod(List<?> o) { // then List<?>method will be called over Collection<?>.

Comment: "@Java Player: I keep visiting this forum in office as well and keep update myself as soon as possible. BTW did you try it? If you tried then please drop the conclusion here.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this is wrong. With the specified change it would call `overloadedMethod(List<?>)` (it wouldn't call `overloadedMethod(ArrayList<?>)` because `method` takes a `List`.